# System.ArgumentException when deploying Published app

Tags: c#, clickonce, syncfusion

I have an issue with a deployed app and the issue seems to be related to some Syncfusion components.

```
Syncfusion.Core
Syncfusion.Shared.Wpf
```

If I don't include them in the published packaged that I create using Visual Studio (2012), then when I deploy and try to run that app I get an error saying that Syncfusion.Core needs to be installed in the GAC.

On Synfusion site it says I can either install to GAC or include the dll with the package. So, if I include the dll files in the published packaged I now get the following error when running the app.

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [19/03/2013 08:49:00] System.ArgumentException
    - Value does not fall within the expected range.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

Any ideas of the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install the Syncfusion assemblies into the GAC location or else ship the assemblies with the package.

In order to resolve the reported error, could you please refer the KB article mentioned below ?

http://www.syncfusion.com/support/kb/2110

Note: Syncfusion had removed run-time licensing for all Essential Studio products from the version 8.2.0.x. So, it is not required to embed the license.licx file in your project that uses the latest version assemblies.

Please let us know, if you have any queries.

Regards,
Sivaguru S